# Nodes with links are closer than nodes without links in force layout d3.js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Nodes with links are closer to each other than nodes without links,how do i keep distance between them same.Here is sample code:

```
scope.force = d3.layout.force()
                        .gravity(.2)
                        .distance(100)
                        .charge(function(){
                            if(nodes.length > 20){
                                return -700;
                            }
                            return -2000;
                        })
                        .size([700, 700]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is [linkDistance](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkDistance)? You can set it to the same value as your distance() value (100).

```
scope.force = d3.layout.force()
                        .gravity(.2)
                        .distance(100)
                        .linkDistance(100)
                        .charge(function(){
                            if(nodes.length > 20){
                                return -700;
                            }
                            return -2000;
                        })
                        .size([700, 700]);
```

Comment: Hi vtosh , i tried this solution , the layout behaves very weird with this solution . A node is placed at one end and other connected node at very weird positions

Comment: Hi vtosh , linkDistance set to 100 also doesn't solve issue .